# Where I can find the product category page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am newbie in Magento. I want to edit the product category page but facing problem in finding that. I am unable to find the exact file of category.

I don't know where this page is located.

As far as i have seen, the package name is rwd. So, I access `"app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\"` this directory, 
but don't know where I have to look now.

If there is a page **engagement.html** as product category page, then what will be the location of the file ? which file i need to override ? Can anybody please help me out?

Comment: Turn on the template path hint and can see the exact file path.
http://help.sweettoothrewards.com/article/434-how-do-i-turn-on-template-path-hints

Comment: I enabled the template path but how or where I can see the path? I can't see anything on the site.

Comment: Gotcha. It's visible on the main site. Thanks. One up-vote for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

In by deafult rwd magento theme, category product page path as below:

```
app\design\frontend\{package_name}\{theme_name}\template\catalog\product\view.phtml
```

And if you have custom template used in your theme, then you have to define in block as template file.